# ¿Como hago para que en un formulario se haga required minimo 1 de 2 inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy haciendo un  formulario en html (y poquito de php) en el cual la mayoría de los input son required excepto 2 que en realidad uno de los dos debe ser requerido para completar el formulario pero si o si 1 de los 2.
Quiero hacer un if en js o Jquery que diga que si uno de esos input está vacio, el otro debe ser requerido o si ambos estan vacios que sean requeridos. (en JS estaba probando solamente si el if funcionaba asi pero nunca me funciono)

```js
> Siempre me muestra como que falta el expte, obviamente mi intencion es que se transforme en requerido uno de los dos o ambos pero no que aparezca un alert

function required2() {
       
        if (cuij == ' ' && expte ==' ') {
            alert('Se requieren ambos');
        } else if (expte == ' '){
            alert('Se requiere el CUIJ');
        }
        else {
            alert('Se requiere el EXPTE');
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles/style.css'>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="#" method="post" id='form'>
            <fieldset

> aca arranca el formulario en el cual expte y cuij son los dos de los que 1 debe ser requerido para terminar el formulario

                <legend align='center'>AFILIADO:</legend>
                <label for='n° profesional'>N° del Profesional:</label>
                <input type='number'><br>  
                <label for='apellido'>Apellido:</label>
                <input type='text'> 
            </fieldset> <br>

            <fieldset>
                <legend align='center'>N° DE ORDEN:</legend>
                <br>
            </fieldset> <br>

            <fieldset>
                <legend align='center'>N° AFILIADO:</legend>
                <label for='dni'>DNI: </label>
                <input type='number'> <br>
                <label for='apellido'>APELLIDO:</label>
                <input type='text'>
            </fieldset> <br>

            <fieldset>
                <label for='N° del Profesional' >Fecha de regulacion:</label>
                <input type='date' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' min='1947-01-01' max='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' required> <br>
                <label for='caratula' id='caratula'>Caratula: </label>
                <input type='text' required> <br>
                <label for='honorario regulado'>Honorario regulado:</label>
                <input type='number' required>
                <label for='jus' class='label2'>JUS</label>
                <input type='number' required> <br>
                <label for='observacion'>Observacion:</label>
                <input type='text'>
                <label for='cuij' id='cuij' class='label2'>CUIJ</label>
                <input type='text'><br>
                <label for='nro. de auto' class='expte'>Nro. de auto:</label>
                <input type='number' required>
                <label for='expediente' id='expte' class='expte label2'>Expediente:</label>
                <input type='text'>
                <label for='año expediente' class='expte label2'>Año expediente:</label>
                <input type='date' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' min='1948-01-01' max='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' required><br>
                <label for='circuscripcion' required>Circunscripcion:</label>
                <input type='number' required>
                <label for='tribunal'class='label2'>Tribunal</label>
                <input type='number' required><br>
                <label for='cam/juz'>Camara/Juzgado</label>
                <input type='number' required><br>
                <label for='nomin/sala'>Nominacion/Sala</label>
                <input type='number' required><br>
                <label for='libro'>Libro</label>
                <input type='number' required>
                <label for='folio' class='label2'>Folio (Hoja)</label>
                <input type='number' required><br>
                <label for='grupo'>Grupo</label>
                <input type='number' required>
            </fieldset><br>
                <input type='submit' onclick='required2()' id='enviar'>
                <input type='reset' id='reset'> <br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src='js/form.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Las comillas no deberían tener un espacio en blanco entre ellas, pues con eso un input vacío no encajaría en la condición

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo tu pregunta hice un codigo en **JQuery** que valida los dos campos opcionales y hace la siguiente evaluacion:

1) Si ambos campos estan vacio no procesa el formulario e indica cual esta vacio
2) Si uno de los campos esta vacio solamente avisa cual es el campo vacio y procesa el formulario.

Ahora bien:

Debes colocar un atributo name a los campos que vas a validar opcionalmente para poder buscarlos, (no se que metodo de serializacion estas usando pero a mi punto de vista le falta los atributos names.

Explicacion del codigo:

1) Se le colocaron atributos names para localizar los inputs a evaluar:

```
<label for='cuij' id='cuij' class='label2'>CUIJ</label>
<input type='text'name="cuij"><br>
```

Y esta linea:

```
<label for='expediente' id='expte' class='expte label2'>Expediente:</label>
<input type='text' name="expte">
```

2) Carga del JQuery

```
<script src='js/form.js'></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" 
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

3) Lectura de la cantidad de datos en cada campo

```
var  cuij = $("input[name='cuij']").val();
var expte = $("input[name='expte']").val();
```

4) Remover la asignacion por Jquery de campos requeridos **para cuij y expte**

```
// borrar campo requerido
$("input[name='cuij']").removeAttr("required");
$("input[name='expte']").removeAttr("required");
```

5) Condicion si cuij y expte tiene valor entonces solo avisa **EN cuij**

```
 // cuij requeridos
  if (cuij.length==0 && expte.length > 0) {    
                    alert('Campo [cuij] es requerido');
  };
```

6) Condicion si  expte esta vacio y cuij tiene valor solo avisa **EN expte**

```
// expte requeridos
if(cuij.length>0 && expte.length==0) {
                alert('Campo [expte] es requerido');
};
```

7) Condicion si ambos estan vacios agrega que ambos campos son requeridos y avisa

```
// cuij y expte requeridos
if (cuij.length==0 &&  expte.length==0) {
                   $("input[name='cuij']").attr("required", "required");
                   $("input[name='expte']").attr("required", "required");
                   alert('Campo [cuij] y [expte] es requerido');
};
```

Adjunto el codigo con los cambios hechos:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles/style.css'>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="salida.php" method="post" id='form'>
            <fieldset> aca arranca el formulario en el cual expte y cuij son los dos de los que 1 debe ser requerido para terminar el formulario

                <legend align='center'>AFILIADO:</legend>
                <label for='n° profesional'>N° del Profesional:</label>
                <input type='number'><br>  
                <label for='apellido'>Apellido:</label>
                <input type='text'> 
            </fieldset> <br>

            <fieldset>
                <legend align='center'>N° DE ORDEN:</legend>
                <br>
            </fieldset> <br>

            <fieldset>
                <legend align='center'>N° AFILIADO:</legend>
                <label for='dni'>DNI: </label>
                <input type='number'> <br>
                <label for='apellido'>APELLIDO:</label>
                <input type='text'>
            </fieldset> <br>

            <fieldset>

                <label for='N° del Profesional' >Fecha de regulacion:</label>
                <input type='date' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' min='1947-01-01' max='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' required> <br>
                <label for='caratula' id='caratula'>Caratula: </label>
                <input type='text' required> <br>
                <label for='honorario regulado'>Honorario regulado:</label>
                <input type='number' required>
                <label for='jus' class='label2'>JUS</label>
                <input type='number' required> <br>
                <label for='observacion'>Observacion:</label>
                <input type='text'>

                    <label for='cuij' id='cuij' class='label2'>CUIJ</label>
                    <input type='text'name="cuij"><br>

                <label for='nro. de auto' class='expte'>Nro. de auto:</label>
                <input type='number' required>

                    <label for='expediente' id='expte' class='expte label2'>Expediente:</label>
                    <input type='text' name="expte">

                <label for='año expediente' class='expte label2'>Año expediente:</label>
                <input type='date' value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' min='1948-01-01' max='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' required><br>
                <label for='circuscripcion' required>Circunscripcion:</label>
                <input type='number' required>
                <label for='tribunal'class='label2'>Tribunal</label>
                <input type='number' required><br>
                <label for='cam/juz'>Camara/Juzgado</label>
                <input type='number' required><br>
                <label for='nomin/sala'>Nominacion/Sala</label>
                <input type='number' required><br>
                <label for='libro'>Libro</label>
                <input type='number' required>
                <label for='folio' class='label2'>Folio (Hoja)</label>
                <input type='number' required><br>
                <label for='grupo'>Grupo</label>
                <input type='number' required>
            </fieldset><br>

                <input type='submit' id='enviar'>
                <input type='reset' id='reset'> <br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src='js/form.js'></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" 
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

     <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // validar campos opcionales
        $('#enviar').click(function(e){
            var  cuij = $("input[name='cuij']").val();
            var expte = $("input[name='expte']").val();
            // borrar campo requerido
            $("input[name='cuij']").removeAttr("required");
            $("input[name='expte']").removeAttr("required");
            // cuij requeridos
            if (cuij.length==0 && expte.length > 0) {    
                    alert('Campo [cuij] es requerido');
            }; 
            // expte requeridos
            if(cuij.length>0 && expte.length==0) {
                   alert('Campo [expte] es requerido');
            }; 
            // cuij y expte requeridos
            if (cuij.length==0 &&  expte.length==0) {
                   $("input[name='cuij']").attr("required", "required");
                   $("input[name='expte']").attr("required", "required");
                   alert('Campo [cuij] y [expte] es requerido');
            };
        });

      });
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Espero que pueda ser de ayuda...

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de gran ayuda. pude simplificar un poco mas el codigo poniendo directamente que ambos por defectos sean required y creando un if preguntando que si uno era > 0 y el otro == 0, al == se le saque el attr required y funciono! pero sin tu código no lo pudiera haber hecho, muchas gracias!